# set media player volume on button click event no working

Tags: android

when I click button to set volume 0, it works correctly. But when I click again to set volume 75, it is not working.

```
btn_sound=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sound);
    btn_sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isMute){
                isMute=false;
                Music.setPlayerVolume(75, 75);
                btn_sound.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_normal);
            }else {
                isMute=true;
                Music.setPlayerVolume(0, 0);
                btn_sound.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound_silent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Music.java class:

```
public class Music {
static MediaPlayer player=null;
public static MediaPlayer getPlayer(Activity activity){
    if(player==null){
        player = MediaPlayer.create(activity, R.raw.bac_music);
    }
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.setVolume(75, 75);
    return player;
}
public static void setPlayerVolume(float a,float b){
    player.setVolume(a,b);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

[MediaPlayer.setVolume(float, float)](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float,%20float)) takes float values from 0f to 1f, you should invoke it like this:

```
player.setVolume(0.75f, 0.75f);
```